# Jquery Image Fade Out

Tags: jquery, hover

I am using this jquery to try and fade out my image and show whats underneath. It works perfect except when you hover over it multiply times. Then it freaks out and starts going in and out over and over again. Is there something I can do about that?

```
$('#contentPosters li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').fadeOut();
}, 
function(){
    $(this).find('img').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#contentPosters li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo('fast',0);
}, 
function(){
    $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo('fast',1);
});
```

Use **stop()** AND **fadeTo**

**stop()** is for stopping current animation.

**fadeTo()** usage is because when you stop the animation during **fadeIn** / **fadeOut**, the opacity will not reset to 100%, and your image will become invisible over the time.

Comment: This seems to work except the elements underneath it dont work. I cant click a link.

Comment: fadeTo doesn't HIDE the element totally. Use this update http://jsfiddle.net/wSYmg/1/

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, thought it didn't matter but I guess I was wrong. Either way thanks for the help. On a side note is there anything in between fast and slow?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Add "stop()" before your animation function.

```
$('#contentPosters li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').stop().fadeOut();
}, 
function(){
    $(this).find('img').stop().fadeIn();
});
```

Ok above would work technically, but I think a better way for it to work would be.

```
var delay = 200;
$('#contentPosters li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').dequeue().fadeTo(delay,0);
}, 
function(){
    $(this).find('img').dequeue().fadeTo(delay,1);
});
```

Comment: This seems to work except for some reason now sometimes when my mouse goes away it wont show the img again.

Comment: @Jacinto Right, the user didn't check the functionality before posting the code.

Comment: hmmmm....Jo I tried your new code and it does not fade back to the iamge. @Avetarman what did he do wrong?

Comment: sorry my second line was meant to be fadeTo instead of fadeIn... updated the code

Comment: @Jo why is doing that better? Also doing it like this causes the same problem as bellow, I have a link that is no longer clickable.

Comment: could you add a snippet of how your link, li, and image all layout?

Comment: i have found dequeue() to be faster than stop() when dealing with fading, but honestly it comes down to what all of the rest of your JS looks like. I would test both of them and see which feels cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try using .fadeToggle('fast'), it has all the catches covered.</strike>

Looks like stop() doesn't work with the default .fadeToggle, since it would stop the animation while the opacity is halfway through.

```
$('#contentPosters li').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo(200,'mouseleave'==e.type)
});
```

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/w2vus/</strike>

**edit:** new fiddle works now

**latest update: This is the cleanest solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/xBtpC/

```
$('#contentPosters li').hover(function(e) {
  $(this).find('img').stop(true,true).fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't "have all catches covered".

Comment: @avetarman, wow, you're right.  The queue goes haywire.  I always thought the .toggle features handled those inherently.